# Left Join In Entity Framework 6

Tags: mysql, vb.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I Have some old SQL code that uses a left join when querying from database. I have no idea how to do this using EF, but i can imagine it is much simpler. (VB.NET newest version)

Here is SQL code:

```
'Now Change each of the dimension values on the EDD stack to EDD dimension Values
' - if Not deleted And on the stack

SqlString = "SELECT * FROM StackUp " +
            "LEFT JOIN StackUpItems On IdStackUp=StackUpID " +
            "LEFT JOIN DimensionValues ON DimensionValuesId=IdDimensionvalues " +
            "WHERE IdStackUp=" + StackUpId.ToString + " AND " +
            "isnull(IsDimensionValuesDeleted,0)=0 AND isnull(StackUpItems.IsDeleted,0)=0  ;"
SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlString, SqlConnectionString)
TableNow = New DataTable
SqlDataAdapter.Fill(TableNow)
```

I have tried a few things but I have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to these types of query's.

Here is code for my object from database:

```
Function ToggleIsEDD(ByVal StackUpId) As Boolean

  'main try
  Try
      Dim IdNow As Integer = StackUpId
      Dim StackUpNow As IEnumerable(Of Stackup) = (From a In Db.Stackup Where a.IdStackup = IdNow).ToList
```

Comment: Assuming your Stackup class has navigation properties for StackUpItems  and DimensionValues you can use those in your query: From a In Db.Stackup Where a.IdStackup = IdNow && a.StackUpItems.IsDeleted && a.DimensionValues.IsDeleted...

Comment: That almost worked perfectly! Just had to change a little bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got to work:

```
''Now Change each of the dimension values on the EDD stack to EDD dimension Values
        '' - if Not deleted And on the stack
        '================================================================
        'This might need "or not null" statements within query as well
        '================================================================
        StackUpNow = (From a In Db.StackupItems
                      Where a.IdStackupItem =
                          IdNow And Not a.Stackup.IsDeleted And Not a.DimensionValues.IsDimensionValuesDeleted
                          ).ToList
```